# Add a facebook page in the "via application" link

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I've developed an android mobile application, which post on Facebook wall. So after giving the post, it shows **"via MyAppName"** under the post. And it shows as a link. If I click it, it shows
**The page you requested was not found**.

Now I want to add a Facebook page with this link, suppose a publicity page for my app. Or may be a URL of my application link on the Play store.

How can I do that? Will my app have any negative effect if I do that!
Currently only selected option is  **"Native Android App"** under **"Select how your app integrates with Facebook"** on the Facebook developers' site for this app.
I've searched a lot, but can't find anything......... Please help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually links to the Canvas URL (dev settings). If you did not set one, you get the error message.
So, if you want the link to lead somewhere, just use a canvas URL and redirect to a page.

Keep in mind that you need a server with SSL for that, btw.